# Create a clean release git repo from a private development repo

Tags: git

I have a private git repo in which I develop a software. At some point, I want to make parts of that software public - lacking some features of the dev version. Therefore, I would like to create a second, release repository from the dev one. However, the release repo should *not* contain some files of the dev version. On the other hand, I want to be able to keep track of the changes in the dev version, i.e., I want to be able to pull changes from the dev repo into the release repo. How do I do this with git?

Comment: And for updates from the dev to the release repo I copy the files again?

Comment: IMHO your public project should become a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) of your private project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't... you write a script that copies only the relevant files to a second folder that is managed by git, do a git commit and git push to the release repository

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by only pushing the release branch (by convention, master) to the public repository added as a new remote, and keep all your other branches only on the private repo.

```
git remote add public-repo-alias <public-repo-address> (first time config only)
git push public-repo-alias master
```

This requires you to use at least a basic [feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow), which you should be doing anyway.

Note that if the privacy of unfinished features you've completed so far is a concern and you haven't been following some kind of a feature branch workflow, then you can't eradicate the unwanted files from history without overwriting it. Somewhere along the way the release branch will have a "removed foo, baz and bar" commit, and the code will be recoverable.

Also note that the standard way of doing things would be to simply use a reasonable workflow with master as the release branch, and keep everything public... If you're open sourcing software then why not let people see the development branches and contribute?

Comment: I guess this would be the way to go, but I haven't strictly followed such a workflow. So, I either have to restructure the project from scratch, or go back to the script solution proposed by yorammi. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you are concerned only about the features in Dev, you should consider using [Features Toggles](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html) pattern. That is adding configuration keys to enable/disable features.

This pattern is a basic one to do [Continuous Integration/Deployment](https://continuousdelivery.com/implementing/patterns/)